# Gold foil material for export

Tags: materials, export

I'm trying to create a gold foil material for a mesh.
My first attempts work quite well:

[image: Suzanne with my material]

This is the material in the node editor:

[image]

The problem is that I have to export my object to an .x- or .obj-Format. Well, I can, but I does not export my gold foil.
I know I can use the  Displace-Modifier, but it's not working correctly - espacially because I just want to apply the material of some parts of the 
mesh.
Any solutions? Can I apply the changes by the displacement node to the mesh?

Comment: what is the destination program for your object? You might have to write your own shaders or replicate the shader setup yourself in the other program.

Comment: You should read up on the [.obj specifications](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/mtl/), and what to expect from the way it stores material information.. it has limitations..

Comment: @zeffii: The destination software is DigitalSky by SkyScan. I know I can't export the displacement directly... but I don't know how to use the Displace-Modifier in this case. I'm questioning if it's possible to apply the changes to the mesh made by the Displacement-Material-Node or how to use the Modifier in this case.

Comment: If normal mapping is supported in digital sky, you can try to bake it.

Comment: @poor: I don't if normal mapping is supported in DS, but I will it out. How can I bake the normal map?

by the way: Sorry for the typo - it's of course Sky-Skan, not SkyScan.